# Disk ejected but still show up in Disk Utility?

Tags: disk-utility, usb, external-disk, mount

I have this external (USB) drive that can't seem to be disconnected correctly.  Whenever I eject the drive, it won't disappear from Disk Utility.  Afterwards when the drive gets re-connected again, it cannot be mounted. At this stage, I would need to reboot the Mac to get the drive to mount again.

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

Ejecting from the Terminal via `diskutil eject /dev/disk2` returns a `Disk /dev/disk2 ejected` message and unmounts the disk.  However the disk still shows up both in Disk Utility and `diskutil list`.

Furthermore even after the USB cable is disconnected, the disk still shows in both Disk Utility lists — GUI and command line.

How can I solve this?

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75)

Comment: What happens if you issue the command in Terminal:  `diskutil eject disk2`?

Comment: @Allan Question updated with new information.

Comment: Then, if you issue the command `diskutil unmountDisk disk2`? (you *may* need to use `sudo`, but try without first).

Comment: I'm getting this on Ventura with an M1 MacBook Air and a brand new Toshiba HD I just bought. `diskutil unmountDisk`Unmount of all volumes on disk4 was successful` but I don't believe it and its little blue light still flashes sometimes afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird as it is, this seems to be the solution:

1. Remove the disk from Time Machine's list of backup destination drives.
2. Remove file `tmbootpicker.efi` from the drive's root directory.
3. Remove file `/var/db/volinfo.database`
4. After restarting and able to mount the drive again, re-add the drive to Time Machine.

Ejecting the drive seems to work now — it finally disappears from Disk Utility's list after the USB cable is unplugged.